# Enable pin current limiting resistor?

Tags: power-supply, design, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I was looking at the [AOZ1280CI](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1280CI.pdf) DC-DC buck converter, and I'm having trouble properly interpreting the datasheet concerning the enable pin.

In the pinout description, it states:

> Enable pin. The enable pin is active high. Connect EN pin to VIN through current limiting
>   resistor. Do not leave the EN pin floating.

However, they don't offer any way to calculate the value of the current-limiting resistor or what an acceptable value is. The upper limit I figured is `(12V - 1.4V) / 3 uA = 3.5 Mohms`, but between a short and this limit are a ton of different possible values.

Later on in the datasheet, they state:

> The EN pin of the AOZ1280 is active high. Connect the
>   EN pin to VIN if the enable function is not used. Pulling
>   EN to ground will disable the AOZ1280. Do not leave EN
>   open.

Somehow I interpret this as being that the EN pin can be shorted to VIN to have the output always enabled. I am misinterpreting this? Can I short the EN pin to GND/VIN without a current-limit resistor and expect safe operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saying that you just need a pull-up resistor, so that a logic high is present on the Enable pin. A weak pull-up is all that is needed, with consideration for current draw. Which resistor you use is not a design critical choice, it's left to the designer to figure out (i.e. if you use a bunch of the same value resistor for other pull-ups, use the same here, or if it's battery powered vs ac powered, a higher one is recommended vs a lower one.)

What you need for a weak pull-up:
1) High enough value to limit current draw as needed
2) Low enough to provide the response time needed (Especially in i2c specifications) (i.e. not to interfere with mcu disabling of the regulator)

Too low, and you risk high current draw if you assert the Enable pin (Via button or microcontroller). You also risk your microcontoller not being able to bring the pin down to the correct logic low voltage.

Too high, and the line won't go from logic low to logic high fast enough, but that's really an issue with communication busses and high frequency timing.

**Now, for practical use, if you don't need to disable the regulator, you probably don't need the pull-up resistor. Since this is a user asserted pin, if you assert the pin low, without a pull-up resistor, you would be creating a short circuit (Vcc to ground), but if you have no intention of disabling the regulator, there is no risk of that. Good practice does dictate you add in the resistor though, even if you won't assert the pin.**

From Sparkfun's [Pull-Up Resistor guide](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/218):

> The general rule for condition 2 is to use a pull-up resistor (R1) that is an order of magnitude (1/10th) less than the input impedance (R2) of the input pin. An input pin on a microcontroller has an impedance that varies around 100k-1MOhm. For this discussion, impedance is just a fancy way of saying resistance and is represented by R2 in the picture above. So, when the button is not pressed, a very small amount of current flows from VCC through R1 and into the input pin. The pull-up resistor R1 and input pin impedance R2 divides the voltage, and this voltage needs to be high enough for the input pin to read a high state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd connect it with a 10k or 100k Pull-up to VIN to keep the device active all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken input voltage variations into account - maybe you know your Vin will never fall below 12V so that's not a criticism: however I would use the minimum operating voltage 3V and suggest (3V-1.2V)/3ua = 0.6M as an upper limit.

"Connect the EN pin to VIN if the enable function is not used" sanctions 0 ohms as a lower limit.

It's a high impedance input so it won't draw more that the rated 3 uA, so no normal need for current limiting.

However I wouldn't short them together : Tom's suggestion of 10-100k is good unless you need to save every last resistor. Or a spare resistor in a multi-pack for example, or whatever value you use in bulk elsewhere on the board.

Then at test, you can pull EN to 0V to check operation, and increase your test coverage. That doesn't work if it is shorted...

Answer (score 0):

From page 7:

> The voltage on the EN pin must be above 1.2 V to enable the AOZ1280. When voltage on the EN pin falls below 0.4 V, the AOZ1280 is disabled

If the pin can only sink \$3 \mu A\$ (which is implied on page 7) then even a 1 ohm resistor would not drop enough voltage to cause the enable to malfunction at the bare minimum 3V input DC level. This means that a direct tie should not cause a malfunction.

That being said, it's usually a good idea to put a physical component there in case you ever change your mind and want to have control of the enable pin.